# Android setting width to ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT gives -1

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I have this code when I'm creating my popup

```
val width = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
```

The popup is showing up and have a full width as wanted. But for some reasons the width variable gets assigned -1 and I use that variable to populate other things in the popup so they get an negative width and don't show up. How come this gives back -1 when the popup gets full width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> public static final int MATCH_PARENT Special value for the height or
> width requested by a View. MATCH_PARENT means that the view wants to
> be as big as its parent, minus the parent's padding, if any.
> Introduced in API Level 8.
>
> Constant Value: -1 (0xffffffff)  ([+](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams#MATCH_PARENT))

To get the width of specific view, you can do as below :

```
int width = specificView.getWidth();
```

Comment: Correct, but mind that the width of a view is available after "onLayout" method gets called

Answer (score 2):

The width of your view (guess `ConstraintLayout`) is not static, it depends on the device on which the view is rendered to.
In kotlin you have a convenient method to calculate view dimensions at runtime:

```kotlin
view.doOnLayout {
    it.measuredWidth
    it.measuredHeight
}
```